# class UtcTimeStamp/UtcDate/LocalTimeStamp/LocalData in quickfix

Tags: c++, timestamp, quickfix

I am using quickfix C++ lib.
If a FIX message field type is of UtcTimeStamp for example tag 62 (ValidUntilTime), how can I convert its value into a local time? Expecially I'd like to learn whether I can use the provided classes like LocalTimeStamp/LocalData with this UtcTimeStamp as input value.

Answer (score 0):

The UtcTimeStamp type has a member function getTimeT() which returns the value as the more familiar time_t struct. There are many other members available if all you want is some specific component, such as minutes. See the full reference at

[QuickFix UtcTimeStamp](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_utc_time_stamp.html)

Comment: Assume I can use getTimeT() to get time_t. Can I pass its value directly to LocalTimeStamp and call LocalTimeStamp's other function to get local time?